# Prepend number to the beginning of some lines in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a file with some numbers

for example

```
$cat file
347678126
345258126
4378126
349878126
346123126
9678130
344838126
5678126
```

And i need add the number 34 to a line if the line does not begin with 34, and if the line begins in 34 not add anything

Output:

```
$cat file
347678126
345258126
344378126
349878126
346123126
349678130
344838126
345678126
```

I am intenting with a awk:

```
cat file | awk '{print 34$1}' > file2
```

But it add 34 to all lines.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is handy to edit file in-place

```
sed -i '/^34/!s/^/34/' file
```

Comment: say me sed: illegal option -- i

Comment: What does `sed --version` output?

Comment: AFAIK, `-i` is a very old option & unless, you have a custom busybox like `sed`, `-i` should be supported. Else, you can use a temp-file : `sed '/^34/!s/^/34/' file > file.bak; mv file.bak file`

Comment: @anishane: `sed -i` is utterly non-portable.  It may be "old" in the sense that it has been in gnu-sed for a long time, but there are many sed in which the option has never been valid and it has never been standard.

Comment: If yours doesn't have `-i`, just drop the option and use redirection instead. Where supported, `sed -i` will replace the existing file "in place".

Comment: @alexander if you're on a Mac, `-i` requires an argument.  If you really don't want a backup file you can use the empty string, `-i ''`

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there, you just have to filter out the lines that do start with 34:

```
awk '!/^34/{printf 34}1' file
```

Comment: Maybe also note that you fixed the [UUoC](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).